# Android_tutorial_pubsub errors on Eclipse

Tags: ros, path, android-core, build, android-gingerbread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to set up an environment for developing an ROS Android application for some time but have no luck so far. I followed the tutorial [Installing/building rosjava_core & android_core](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/building.html) and got kinda stuck on the last step.

After successfully execute `./gradlew debug` I tried to create a new Android Project from existing code by browsing to the "android_tutorial_teleop". Then I add all of the jars in the libs directory to the project build path by "Configuring Build Path". But there are still lots of error at my MainActivity.java where the import failed (cannot be resolved) with the "red lines" below them. Any ideas where I did wrong and how to solve them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44274/android_tutorial_pubsub-errors-on-eclipse/) by [steven7](https://answers.ros.org/users/3213/steven7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you have the latest ADT and Android SDK installed. There have been a lot of changes in the way that dependencies are handled.

Also, I've seen Eclipse builds of Android projects get stuck in a bad state many times. Not ideal. My personal recipe:

1. Disable automatic building
2. Do a clean build
3. Refresh and build projects starting from the bottom of the dependency tree
4. Repeat until successful

Unfortunately, this problem is not part of rosjava or the rosjava build process. I have no ability to actually make it easier :(

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4